# Installing MongoDB on CentOS 5.5 32bits

Tags: php, mongodb, centos

I'm trying to install mongoDB on my CentOS 5.5 32bits VPS server which is going without any trouble until I try to install the PHP driver.

Logged in as root i do

```
$ pecl install mongo
```

Resulting in the error

> Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
>   $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

I tried to manually download it from github but when executing a phpize on that one I get the same error.

Hopefully someone can help me with installing the driver.

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault. In the meantime, try installing `autoconf`, `make` and `gcc` via yum

Comment: I agree that you'll surely have better luck on serverfault. you could also install mongo via yum. maybe [this](http://www.easyflip.co.uk/farnell_2010PT/ebook.html) helps.

Comment: Thanks for the awnsers, @Phil: your comment did the trick.
Thanks again!

Comment: @Phil, can you post your comment as an answer so that sandermangel can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the correct permissions to install mongodb
2. Install the development tools (quite a lot of packages to install, you may want to install only some if you have a low bandwidth or not enough disk space): `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, i managed to do it by installing try installing autoconf, make and gcc via yum and then $sudo pecl install mongo

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `autoconf`, `make` and `gcc` via yum, then `sudo pecl install mongo`